# How to enable syntax help on sublime Text 3?

Tags: ide, sublimetext2, sublimetext3

Currently I use Komodo Edit and, Komodo helps me with syntax remembrance or highlighting, I can't seem to get any other IDE to do that.  I was wondering how do you enable it in sublime Text 2 or 3?  Notice in the image below, there is a drop down menu highlighting setInterval. I would like that for Sublime Text Editor, for it to help me with built in functions or methods of whatever language I'm using.

[image: Helps With Syntax]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sublime Text has packages that you can install. Here's one that does something like your screenshot for autocompletes: http://sublimecodeintel.github.io/SublimeCodeIntel/

Different languages have different autocomplete packages. Here's one for Javascript: https://packagecontrol.io/packages/JavaScript%20Completions

And here's one for Python: https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Anaconda

Comment: Thanks for the link. Sometimes I get frustrated when I can't remember a built in function or method, so the autocomplete helps out.

Comment: No problem! The other packages are also worth checking out. There are definitely a lot of handy ones available